# Compute math expression given in xml string using java

Tags: java, xml, recursion, data-structures, tree

Assumption is that

- when we see start element if number push it in number stack
- if we see start element of function/add/multiply push it in the operator stack
- when we see end element of function/add/multiply we pop one operator and required values from number stack
- we do the math operation and push back to number stack the result

The problem is not able to think of add with three multiply

XML String:

```
<function value="largest">
   <multiply>
      <numbr value="2" />
      <numbr value="3" />
   </multiply>
   <add>
      <multiply>
         <numbr value="5" />
         <numbr value="6" />
      </multiply>
      <multiply>
         <numbr value="7" />
         <numbr value="8" />
      </multiply>
       <multiply>
         <numbr value="7" />
         <numbr value="7" />
         <numbr value="7" />
      </multiply>
   </add>
</function>
```

Some rough Java Code :

```
    Stack<Value> value = new Stack<>();
    Stack<Operator> operator = new Stack<>();
    XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
    InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes());
    XMLStreamReader reader = factory.createXMLStreamReader(stream);
 while (reader.hasNext()) {
      int event = reader.next();
      switch (event) {
        case XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT:
          String attributeValue = reader.getAttributeValue(null, "value");
          break;
        case XMLStreamConstants.END_ELEMENT:
          String localName = reader.getLocalName();
          break;
      }
```

[reference link](https://gist.github.com/agrawal-priyank/9031d4dc6b292e20b9c98f0d7762d134)

Comment: It looks like the nested XML structure implies operator precedence, i.e. you just do what the XML says. In which case you just need to evaluate the input in depth-first order.

Comment: ok any example can you share

Comment: I think this has a recursive solution. This problem needs to arrange the data in tree. So you can try think of a recursive solution as of now.

Comment: Use a `Transform` to transform the XML into normal infix expression text, and then use the `ScriptEngine` to evaluate it.

Answer (score 1):

After giving my time on this problem, I found out that it has a recursive solution as the given XML has to arrange the data in the form of `n-ary tree`.
Here's what pseudo code looks like:

```
public class RecursiveProgram{
    /*the recfn is the recursive function to make new call on every new operator tag Example : "add", "multiply"*/
    public static int recfn(String currentOperator){
        int total;
        /*We will use list to store multiple values on which only one operator will perform operations.*/
        ArrayList<Integer> numberlist= new ArrayList<>(); 
        /* now we will continue traversing elements. Assume currentOperator as current xml tag*/
        while(nexttag() != currentOperator.end){ 
            String tag= nexttag();
            if(tag != value){
                /*if tag is operator then make a new call and store its result in numberlist of current operator */
                numberlist.add(recfn(tag)); 
            }else{
                numberlist.add(tag.value);
            }
        }
        /*Once we found the end of the current operator then perform operation on all elements of numberlist.*/ 
        if(currentOperator == "add"){
            total=0;
            for(Integer i : numberlist){
                total+=i;
            }
            return total;
        }else{
            total=1;
            for(Integer i : numberlist){
                total*=i;
            }
            return total;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int total;
        String operator;
        total=recfn(operator); //suould pass start operator

    }
}
```

This answer has lot of analogies pointing to reading tags/values. So it won't compile and run. You have to digest the algorithmic idea and implement it yourself accordingly. Also, I recommend to verify the algorithm with the above sample XML code. If it satisfies, give it a shot.